# SQL - Parse table of multi-column XML Data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have a table filled with XML Data that I am trying to parse. The XML contains multiple columns of data that I am trying to parse. In some cases there are multiple rows of XML data stuffed into the single column of data and in some cases just one. sample data below:

```
<REC><C1>0E5627DF-DBB1-4300-40F2-715A8C96190B</C1><C2>apples</C2></REC>
<REC><C1>59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B</C1><C2>oranges</C2></REC><REC><C1>59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B</C1><C2>grapes</C2></REC><REC><C1>59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B</C1><C2>apples</C2></REC>
<REC><C1>7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA</C1><C2>bananas</C2></REC><REC><C1>7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA</C1><C2>watermelon</C2></REC><REC><C1>7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA</C1><C2>limes</C2></REC>
<REC><C1>38B13BFB-DBAA-C340-40F2-715A8C961942</C1><C2>apples</C2></REC>
<REC><C1>58209738-DB3C-DB00-D01A-7FDA8C9619B5</C1><C2>pears</C2></REC><REC><C1>58209738-DB3C-DB00-D01A-7FDA8C9619B5</C1><C2>limes</C2></REC>
```

What I am trying to do is parse the data into the following 2 column layout

```
C1                                      C2
0E5627DF-DBB1-4300-40F2-715A8C96190B    apples
59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B    oranges
59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B    grapes
59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B    apples
7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA    bananas
7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA    watermelon
7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA    limes
38B13BFB-DBAA-C340-40F2-715A8C961942    apples
58209738-DB3C-DB00-D01A-7FDA8C9619B5    pears
58209738-DB3C-DB00-D01A-7FDA8C9619B5    limes
```

Below is my attempt at it:

```
SELECT Split.XMLD.value('.', 'VARCHAR(500)')
FROM myTable XMLD
CROSS APPLY XMLD.REC.nodes ('/REC') AS Split(XMLD)
```

Any ideas how to parse this?

Clarification: I want to stay with Native MS SQL SQL here. I don't want to use any third party tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 ('<REC><C1>0E5627DF-DBB1-4300-40F2-715A8C96190B</C1><C2>apples</C2></REC>')
,('<REC><C1>59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B</C1><C2>oranges</C2></REC><REC><C1>59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B</C1><C2>grapes</C2></REC><REC><C1>59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B</C1><C2>apples</C2></REC>')
,('<REC><C1>7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA</C1><C2>bananas</C2></REC><REC><C1>7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA</C1><C2>watermelon</C2></REC><REC><C1>7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA</C1><C2>limes</C2></REC>')
,('<REC><C1>38B13BFB-DBAA-C340-40F2-715A8C961942</C1><C2>apples</C2></REC>')
,('<REC><C1>58209738-DB3C-DB00-D01A-7FDA8C9619B5</C1><C2>pears</C2></REC><REC><C1>58209738-DB3C-DB00-D01A-7FDA8C9619B5</C1><C2>limes</C2></REC>');

SELECT ID
      ,r.value(N'(C1/text())[1]','uniqueidentifier') AS C1
      ,r.value(N'(C2/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS C2
FROM @mockupTable AS t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXml.nodes(N'/REC') AS A(r) ;
```

The result

```
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
| ID | C1                                   | C2         |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
| 1  | 0E5627DF-DBB1-4300-40F2-715A8C96190B | apples     |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
| 2  | 59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B | oranges    |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
| 2  | 59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B | grapes     |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
| 2  | 59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B | apples     |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
| 3  | 7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA | bananas    |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
| 3  | 7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA | watermelon |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
| 3  | 7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA | limes      |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
| 4  | 38B13BFB-DBAA-C340-40F2-715A8C961942 | apples     |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
| 5  | 58209738-DB3C-DB00-D01A-7FDA8C9619B5 | pears      |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
| 5  | 58209738-DB3C-DB00-D01A-7FDA8C9619B5 | limes      |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
```

Some things to think about:

- Your XML is not well-formed. There is no root-node. SQL-Server can deal with such XML fragments, but other comsumers might get in troubles.
- If this XML is under your control I'd change the design no to store the C1 value over and over.

Comment: I agree with the non-well formed info, sadly I don't have any sway to control the source.

Comment: @Dave Well Sometimes we have to walk the dirty road 

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really neat way to easily generate the XQuery/XPath query for any XML data no matter the complexity or "ugliness":

It requires SQLHTTP which is a free database/assembly that we created which you can find on our website at: http://sqlhttp.net/documentation/xqueryhelper

First you need to set an XML variable with your data.  Notice that I added a  opening tag and  closing tag.

```
DECLARE @X xml = '<ROOT>
    <REC><C1>0E5627DF-DBB1-4300-40F2-715A8C96190B</C1><C2>apples</C2></REC>
<REC><C1>59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B</C1><C2>oranges</C2></REC><REC><C1>59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B</C1><C2>grapes</C2></REC><REC><C1>59868DA4-DB9D-1384-B07D-715A8C96197B</C1><C2>apples</C2></REC>
<REC><C1>7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA</C1><C2>bananas</C2></REC><REC><C1>7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA</C1><C2>watermelon</C2></REC><REC><C1>7FB8C203-DB30-5340-B07D-715A8C9619FA</C1><C2>limes</C2></REC>
<REC><C1>38B13BFB-DBAA-C340-40F2-715A8C961942</C1><C2>apples</C2></REC>
<REC><C1>58209738-DB3C-DB00-D01A-7FDA8C9619B5</C1><C2>pears</C2></REC><REC><C1>58209738-DB3C-DB00-D01A-7FDA8C9619B5</C1><C2>limes</C2></REC>
</ROOT>'
```

You then execute the following stored procedure:

```
EXEC SQLHTTP.net.XqueryHelper @X
```

In the case, the procedure will output the following four lines:

```
Usage                                             Name   Rows
------------------------------------------------- ------ ------
EXEC SQLHTTP.net.XQueryHelper @X, 'ROOT'          ROOT   1
EXEC SQLHTTP.net.XQueryHelper @X, 'ROOT/REC'      REC    10
EXEC SQLHTTP.net.XQueryHelper @X, 'ROOT/REC/C1'   C1     10
EXEC SQLHTTP.net.XQueryHelper @X, 'ROOT/REC/C2'   C2     10
```

The line you're interested in to get you the ten records with the fruit names is the second line:

```
EXEC SQLHTTP.net.XQueryHelper @X, 'ROOT/REC'
```

The above stored procedure call will then output your XQuery/XPath like this:

```
SELECT  T.C.value(N'C1[1]', N'nvarchar(MAX)') AS [C1]
    ,T.C.value(N'C2[1]', N'nvarchar(MAX)') AS [C2]
FROM @X.nodes(N'/ROOT/REC') T(C)
```

Comment: I do not want to use any non-native tools.